# External 2.5" enclosure SATA power only

Tags: sata, sas, hardware

we have these mini-SAS PCIe SATA III controllers.  Mini-SAS enclosures seem to run about $500, but I can use a $10 mini-SAS-to-SATA adapter cable so then all I need is an external enclosure that provides SATA power and has a way to run the cables into the drives.  Should work?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a shopping/recommendation question, voted to close.

Comment: Yes, it's a question about whether such a product exists.  If so, what is an example.  If not why not.  Where do these questions belong?

Comment: Agree. Question is about technical feasibility. Many admins often face questions like this.

Comment: Gotta love the summary judgement from the admins/bureaucrats.  Always a good way to kill a community...

Answer (score 1):

Google tells me that they exist and can be purchased. Look for "SAS enclosure" and select something with the [right connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_attached_SCSI#Connectors) - SFF-8470 (InfiniBand) is quite common but SFF-8086/7/8 (various mini-SAS) can be found too.

More cheaply, an "external disk array" (disk bays with power/SATA connectors) also exist.

Everything else will depend on your setup - ideally, get something rackmounted, running off your UPS, with a very neat cable connecting to your sever and hopefully it won't be accidentally pulled or lose power.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way more low-budget solution.  As I mentioned in the question, mini-SAS enclosures are about $500, but a mini-SAS to SATA cable is $10.  What I'm looking for is either a product that provides only power and you run your own data cables to the drives, or else a cheap product that can be hacked into filling this role.

Comment: @Chinasaur This is fast approaching shopping, but yes - e.g. http://www.techbuy.com.au/p/130033/HARD_DRIVE_-_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_TOWERS/Addonics/AE5RCS35NSA.asp

Comment: Thanks again, basically I need the right terms to be searching for, then of course I will do my own shopping.  The link is pretty close but it wants power input from a PSU.  What I want is a small box for 4-8 drives with a wall wart.